# Number of posible triangles in a 4×4 dots grid

Tags: permutations, combinations

How many triangles are possible with area 3 Sq cm  In a 4×4 dots grid of dimensions 3cm×3cm?

Comment: Any three distinct points not on a common line form a triangle, don't they?  So you could count all the unordered triples of points from the grid, then subtract the number of those that line up.

Comment: The hard part is counting how many triples are on a single line (colinear).  Fortunately there are not all that many straight lines that pass through more than two grid points.